# plotly: how to add different vertical lines in strip plot with categorical x-axis

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I have a simple strip plot with a categorical x-axis. I want to add a vertical line (on different y-values) for each category.

I am able to to create one vertical line throughout the plot like this:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.strip(df, x="category", y="value")
fig.add_hline(y=191)
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

However, I am unable to plot one vertical line for each category.

### Desired Output

My desired output is something like this:

[image]

I tried adding a shape to the layout, but it did not affect the output:

```
fig.update_layout(shapes=[
    dict( type= 'line',
      yref= 'paper', y0= 180, y1= 180,
      xref= 'x', x0= "cat1", x1= "cat1")])
```

Something like this would probably work if the x-axis is numeric. However, not sure how to specify the category here. If this is the way to go, then I am probably doing it wrong.

How would I be able to add a single horizontal line, as depcited above, with a different y-value for each category?

---

Data to reproduce plot:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "category": ["cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2"],
    "value": [150, 160, 180, 190]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add lines with shapes. There are two types of coordinate axes: x,y axis and paper-based. From your desired output, you can read and specify the x-axis as paper-based and the y-axis as the y-axis value.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['cat1','cat1','cat2','cat2'],'value':[150,160,180,190]})
fig = px.strip(df, x="category", y="value")

fig.update_layout(shapes=[dict(type='line', x0=0.2, y0=180, x1=0.3, y1=180,
                               xref='paper', yref='y',
                               line_width=3, line_color='red'),
                          dict(type='line', x0=0.7, y0=192, x1=0.8, y1=192,
                               xref='paper', yref='y',
                               line_width=3, line_color='red'),
                         ])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Am I interpreting the "paper" coordinates correctly: First line goes from 20%-30% of the width, Seconed line goes from 70%-80% of the width. So if I would have more categories in my dataframe, I would need to hard-code the lines depending on how many categories are added, correct?

Comment: As far as I know, I understand that the coordinates are specified by the xy axis and the paper reference; since the x axis is a categorical variable, I set it manually this time. Depending on the number of categorical variables, I think the position can be derived logically. You can find the official reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/shapes/).

Comment: yep, says it there: "If set to "paper", the `x` position refers to the distance from the left of the plotting area in normalized coordinates where "0" ("1") corresponds to the left (right)"